# Regex allowing for ascii codes 128-165?

Tags: regex

How do you allow ASCII character codes from 128-165 to be included in regular expressions? This includes letters that include tildes and non-english keyboard characters?

Special characters are found [at this link](http://www.asciitable.com/)

How can this be implemented in python and/or javascript?

Comment: What language are you using? The representation might change depending on this...

Comment: @Ben Python and javascript

Comment: @Zac: Unicode or byte strings?

Comment: @nneonneo, I am using unicode

Comment: There is no such thing as ASCII codes > 127. There are many incompatible extensions to ASCII called code pages. The code page in the link you posted is [437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), not Unicode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use hexcode equivalent for your desired unicode code points to create range inside a character class:

```
[\x80-\xA5]

128 -> U+0080 -> \x80  
165 -> U+00A5 -> \xA5
```